# Is [sic] italicized in a quoted sentence that is italicized?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, italics, sic

Is [sic] italicized in a quoted sentence that is italicized, and should I use [sic] after the word *gonna*?

*"If we let you stay here, we're gonna [sic] get phone calls all night."*

Or should it not be italicized?

*"If we let you stay here, we're gonna* [sic] *get phone calls all night."*

I found information about italicizing [sic] in quoted sentences that are not italicized, but I haven't found anything about having it the other way around.

Comment: As a comment extra to the matrix sentence, it should probably be clearly distanced by offseting. I'd not use italics, but I don't know who the biggest rulemaker is hereabouts. The Orthoczar?

Comment: If you are reporting speech, is there any need?

Comment: You normally wouldn't use both quotation marks and italics. It should look like this (with *sic* italicized inside the roman brackets): "If we let you stay here, we're gonna [*sic*] get phone calls all night." If the text is italic, unitialize *sic* inside its italic brackets:  _If we let you stay here, we're gonna [_ sic _] get phone calls all night._ (But you don't need *sic* in this example.)

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane.  Why would you put a *sic* on *gonna*?

Comment: @WeatherVane - I probably don't need to use sic, but the message I'm trying to convey is ridicule on the person who made the original quote.

Comment: @TommyO'Neill - unless you’re in some very formal setting I’d find something else to ridicule them about; use of “gonna” is ***not*** ridicule-worthy.